# Copying a linked list to an array

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

How do i "Copy your linked list to an unordered array"as my teacher put it? I don't know if i should use an iterator or not but doesn't an iterator only copy the linked list to another linked list? Any help welcome.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import jsjf.*;

public class Hw10 
{


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{   
    //-------------------------------------------------
    //Stack
    //-------------------------------------------------
    ArrayListStack <Names> transactions = new ArrayListStack<>();
    //-------------------------------------------------
    //Linked List
    //-------------------------------------------------
    LinkedUnorderedList<Names> list = new LinkedUnorderedList<>();
    //-------------------------------------------------
    // File Scanner
    //-------------------------------------------------
    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    //-------------------------------------------------
    //Variables that the scanner will read in
    //-------------------------------------------------
    int code;
    String name;
    int age;
    Names obj;
    //-------------------------------------------------
    //While Loop to read in file adding to the stack and linked list
    //-------------------------------------------------
    while(fileScan.hasNext())
    {
        code = fileScan.nextInt();
        if(code == 3)
        {
            name = fileScan.next();
            age = fileScan.nextInt();
            obj = new Names(name,age);
            transactions.push(obj);
        }
        else if (code == 1)
        {
            name = fileScan.next();
            age =fileScan.nextInt();
            obj = new Names(name,age);
            list.addToFront(obj);
        }    


    }
    /*
    System.out.print(list.toString());
    System.out.print("-------------");
    System.out.print(transactions.toString());
    */
    //-------------------------------------------------
    //iterator / copy / queue-- copy linked list into unordered array
    //-------------------------------------------------
    ArrayListQueue <Names> aq = new ArrayListQueue();


}
```

Comment: Why don't you ask them?

Comment: An unordered array is one where you've called Collections.shuffle() on it.

Comment: Loop through the `LinkedList` and add each element to an `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single line of code.

Assuming you have a list like this:

```
List<Names> transactions;
```

To convert this to an array simply do:

```
Names[] transactionsArray = transactions.toArray(new Names[transactions.size()]);
```

If you need to randomize the order, simply call `Collections.shuffle()` first:

```
Collections.shuffle(transactions);
```